# Speed of protein conformational change?

Tags: proteins

Although the speed may vary a lot based on factors like protein size/scale of conformational change/type of changes (small block change/arm movement,etc), are there examples of experimental results of time scale of such processes? (Only a single conformational change is considered i.e. the time delay between the begain and the end of a single conformational change event of a single protein (or subunit to be more precise?) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/105/25/8619#) uses "ultrafast 2D-IR vibrational echo chemical-exchange spectroscopy" to track switching between different protein conformations and finds that they take place on the order of 50 pico-seconds ($ 1 \times 10^{-12} $ seconds). [Another paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/100/11/6452) finds something similar but notes that full equilibriation can take on the order or nanoseconds:

> Although the main conformational change of the backbone is completed after only 20 ps, the subsequent equilibration in the new region of conformational space continues for times >16 ns.